# Duplicate Rule not firing for sample data Installed from Trialforce Template

Tags: duplicate-management, template, trialforce

I found out today that a duplicate rule on one of my objects does not fire. After doing a lot of testing I found out that it only doesn't fire for records which were installed as sample data when the org was created with a Trialforce Template.

For example, a record with the name AR was installed as part of the Trailforce Template. When you try to create another record named AR, the duplicate rule does not pop up. When you create a record in the org, for example, OH, then the duplicate rule fires when trying to create another record with the same name.

I have been searching around the documentation for any information about this but have not been able to find any. Does anyone have any insight on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need to log a case with Salesforce, because this sounds like a bug. My immediate guess is that the back end tables that power Duplicate Management aren't populated by the sample data, most likely because of the cloning process ignoring all usual processes (workflows, triggers, etc), since if they were active during the clone, it could cause unintended side effects (the org might not look identical upon cloning).

The "obvious" solution here is to touch the records at least once after the org is cloned, perhaps via a welcome page or something, which should populate the Duplicate Management tables correctly. However, that also seems like an oversight, because those tables should at least be cloned correctly to begin with, even though the rules themselves are not active.